# Access denied on consuming Amazons FBA inventory API

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I was using the Fulfilled by Amazon (FBA) Inventory API( https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/fba/inventory/v20101001/php.html/185-9758808-3007701 ) but getting the following error after executing " ListInventorySupplySample.php " . Can anyone please help me know what went wrong.

```
 $request = new FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Model_ListInventorySupplyRequest();
 $skus= new FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Model_SellerSkuList();
 $skus->setmember(<sku>);

 $request->setSellerId(SELLER_ID);
 $request->setSellerSkus($skus);
 $request->setMarketplace(MARKET_PLACE_ID);
 $request->setQueryStartDateTime(date(DATE_FORMAT,strtotime(date("Y-m-d"). ' - 10 days')));
 invokeListInventorySupply($service, $request);
```

Pasting the request.

```
FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Model_ListInventorySupplyRequest Object
(
_fieldsrotected => Array
(
SellerId => Array
(
FieldValue =>
FieldType => string
)

Marketplace => Array
(
FieldValue =>
FieldType => string
)

SellerSkus => Array
(
FieldValue =>
FieldType => FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Model_SellerSkuList
)

QueryStartDateTime => Array
(
FieldValue => 2014-09-23T00:00:00Z
FieldType => string
)

ResponseGroup => Array
(
FieldValue =>
FieldType => string
)

)

)
```

Pasting the following response.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Fri, 03 Oct 2014 05:43:55 GMT
Server: AmazonMWS
x-mws-request-id: 0d956be3-5811-40f8-9084-4fbd77a83936
x-mws-timestamp: 2014-10-03T05:43:55.676Z
x-mws-response-context: 6n6IpwjyWO/qMfDqEazU02NkR09zL//rlcQMgApvMkfE7zhCMq2n2OtOE0y0F7AT4rO4RyslSkY=
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 295
Vary: User-Agent

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentInventory/2010-10-01/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>
<RequestID>0d956be3-5811-40f8-9084-4fbd77a83936</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Comment: How do you authorize your API Call?

Comment: Do other MWS calls work? Did you double check the MWS credentials in your php code? (I assume you are using Amazon's php library, so the signature calculation should be okay)

Comment: Yes I do checked the credentials. I have updated the question with the request parameters. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved I was using it in my localhost which is behind a proxy. the moment I uploaded it to the server the things worked. Thanks for your help.